# Accessing mac localhost from an iPhone (iOS 10)

Tags: ios, windows, macos, networking, firewall

I've tried from all Stack Overflow's existing answer for this topic but they're not working for me. I've tried using http proxy with Squidman, created local network between my iPhone and my mac with static IP, then accessing it using my machine IP address. I've also tried ping my mac using my Windows pc, it can't ping to my mac but my Mac can ping my Windows, both firewall are disabled.

Any configuration that I missed?

Comment: can you detail if you want to ssh into the Mac or access via http or some other mechanism? The question is not clear.

Comment: You can create a tunnel if you're assessing over http using NGROK (https://ngrok.com/download)

Comment: @Sairam i just want to access it via http.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i've tried localtunnel, but it loads too slow. doesn't NGROK and localtunnel have same purpose and mechanism?

Comment: ngrok and localtunnel are same. ngrok is written in Go and localtunnel is in python. both of them use internet/external servers to tunnel and reverse proxy the requests.

Comment: @Sairam I've found  the main problem, my mac (osx) blocks any ping from other device, although the firewall is disabled. do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: not sure. may be some other application like Littlesnitch may be blocking requests. See if you can telnet IP port (say 80 or 8080). start a python simpleHTTPServer . Disable the firewall. Check the settings on your router.

Answer (score 0):

if your desktop is (192.168.0.101), you need to run your service as `0.0.0.0:8080` (example port). Usually ports are bound to `127.0.0.1`

This way your router can direct requests from 192.168.0.101:8080 to your application. Ensure you undo this in case you exposing sensitive data.

Comment: problem solved buddy, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your mac ip is `$ip`, you can do the following to make port `$port` accessible from your local network:

`$ ssh -R $ip:$port:localhost:$port localhost`

It will relay all requests from `$ip:$port` to the localhost server.

Example:

`$ ssh -R 172.16.0.111:3000:localhost:3000 localhost`

Comment: I've found the main problem, my mac (osx) blocks any ping from other device, although the firewall is disabled. do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: theoretically your router can block pings

Comment: problem solved buddy, thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*

The main problem that causes my Mac can't be accessed by other device is the firewall blocked ICMP. Then I disabled it using this command below:

> pfctl -d

My firewall rules list:

[image: My firewall rules list]